# WooCommerce: change form labels on registration page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook

I'm trying to find the Hook to edit the form label on woocommarce restration page (/my-account/) without luck. I want to add to functions.php what to change username label to. 
Username 
*to:
Username more text*

I do not want to edit template files. Any ide what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the login form labels aren't filterable. You will need to [*override*](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/) the `my-account/form-login.php` template in your theme and make your edits there.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to look and find out is the `hook` for your described text to change to your custom value. A list of all the hooks:

http://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/hook-docs.html

Once you locate the correct hook you can use the [`add_filer()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter) to return the new text of Username eg.

[image]

Optionaly, you can look into the css [`:after`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_after.asp) selector to add some text, hoever this is a hack. These are the only way's withing using template files.

Comment: But is there a Hook to find for this or is it like Helga wrote not possible?